# Cannot install nohup command

Tags: package-management, nohup

I am trying to install the `nohup` command. When I run `sudo apt-get install nohup` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nohup
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? What happens if you run `nohup` in a terminal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no `nohup` package and you don't need to install it.

This command is provided by `coreutils` package as you can see by

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/nohup
```

This package should be installed by default.

Comment: Oh I see. I had the command in a script and I was getting `script.trimmo.sh: 1: ’nohup: not found` so I assumed nohup was not installed but looking more carefully I noticed that it's the ’ that's causing the issue. Thanks